# can we set forkJoin() API request calling one after another, not all at once in angular

Tags: javascript, .net, angular, rxjs

there is one scenario when i tried to make multiple update calls of same endpoint with different body in forkJoin(), server returning

**"Transaction (Process ID 92) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction."**

so API team asking to send  requests one after another, for simplified and as per recommended by TL i'm using forkJoin([]), not for loop based.

can we configure a setting / solution to ask forkJoin(), call the array of Observable API endpoints, one after another,not all at once, Please Help.

```
let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/';
if (this.inviteUpdateBatch.length) {
   forkJoin(this.http.putAsync(`${url}`, data1),
            this.http.putAsync(`${url}`, data2)).subscribe(()=> {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `concat` `rxjs` operator.
for example:

```
     const e = of(1);
     const s = of(2);

     concat(e, s).subscribe(val => {
        console.log('val', val);
     });
```

this will execute the the requests one after the one.